# R Shiny comunication between modules, infinite recursion

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to make a comunication between modules in shiny. My app has an empty data frame of words  in a principal module and i want to add words to this data frame from another module but i get this error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

base_palabras <- reactive({data.frame('Palabra' = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})

ui_ppal <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    column(6, ui_agregar(ns('agregar'))),
    column(6,wellPanel(
      h3('Palabras agregadas'),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = ns('OT_Tabla'))
    ))


  )

}

server_ppal <- function(input, output, session, base){

  ns <- session$ns

  base <- callModule(server_agregar, "agregar", base)

  output$OT_Tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(base(), options = list(dom = 't'))
  })

}

ui_agregar <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(wellPanel(
    textInput(inputId = ns('TC_Nueva'), label = 'Nueva Palabra'),
    actionButton(inputId = ns('TC_Agregar'), label = 'Agregar')
  ))
}

server_agregar <- function(input, output, session, base_t){

  ns <- session$ns

  agregar <- eventReactive(input$TC_Agregar, {
    datos <- rbind(base_t(), data.frame('Palabra' = input$TC_Nueva, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    return(datos)
  })

  return(agregar) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_ppal("principal") 
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(server_ppal, "principal", base_palabras) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```